# Can I use a power supply with more output amperage than the router needs?

Tags: power-over-ethernet

For some reason when I connect a 5m Ethernet cable to my router it works.

When I connect a 10m Ethernet cable it doesn’t work.

- **Router AC Input**: 12V, 2A
- **Charger AC Intput**: 12V, 2A

Can I replace my old power supply with another power supply that has more amperage to power my Wi-Fi router?

Comment: Changing the power supply won't fix a broken Ethernet cable ... PoE works at distances up to 100m.

Comment: @davidpostill I doubt ANY PoE switches run at only 2A.

Comment: @Sickest Yeah, but increasing the amps in the router power supply will probably not solve the problem.

Comment: In my experience when power supplies go bad, weird crap happens. I think he doesn't have the time to order a power supply that's the exact same Amps. He has a PSU that is more amps than needed and trying to see if it's going to break his current router.

Comment: Your question and your problem doesn’t correlate. You are assuming more power to the router would somehow solve the problem of a 10m Ethernet cable not working. One thing won’t cause—or solve—the other thing. Chances are the 10m Ethernet cable is just flaky for some reason.

Comment: Ditto what @JakeGould said. Your question may be suffering from the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The amperage rating on your power supply simply means that the supply can put out *up to* 2 amps, so as long as the voltage matches (12 volts) you could safely use a higher amp power supply for your device.

It never hurts to have a supply that can output more amps than you need, so getting a larger supply could very well be what you need to fix your problem - especially when considering the behavior you described.

Answer (score 3):

I *very highly* doubt the issue is the power supply.  Networking requires very little power and even a cheap, off-brand router is capable of sending a signal 100 meters over copper Ethernet.

More than likely, your 10 meter Ethernet cable is defective.

Additionally, replacing your power supply with one with more amperage is extremely unlikely to make a change.  The amount of power needed to send and receive Ethernet signals is extremely low.  This is not a problem due to the need for "more amperage."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure. If the connector is the same and the voltage is 12V. The ampere value of the new power adapter should be 2A or greater.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the power supply isn't the problem.
If you are using PoE be sure to be using Cat6 or higher cables and preferably solid core ones.

The fact that it works with 5m cable and not with higher means there are losses with the cable you are using.

Even if you would get a higher amperage power supply, it will supply whatever it's requested from the connected device. Just be sure to keep the same voltage.